# Add line breaks after every 10 characters in text field using formula field in salesforce

Tags: formula, formula-field, custom-field, configuration, salesforce-classic

I have a formula field of type Text with maximum length of 255 characters. I need to add new line after every 10 characters. How can I create a formula to dynamically add new lines based on number of characters?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, formulas aren't tailored for this. You'll need an Apex trigger.